# ¿Cómo gestionar correctamente la memoria al cambiar un dato?

Tags: c

Me estoy iniciando en `C` y las principales diferencias con otros lenguajes en los que estoy más avanzado es el uso de la memoria.

Me encuentro realizando el siguiente ejercicio:

> Dada la definición de T en el fichero T.h, se propone implementar:
>   T_mdfyTitle(): Modifica el dato de tipo T recibido como parámetro, con
>   un nuevo nombre. Nota: se debe realizar una gestión correcta de la
>   memoria.

Siendo `T`:

```
typedef struct {
    char* name;
    int code;    
} T;
```

Para mí en Java o C# sería tan simple como un setter, por lo que he implementado:

```
tError T_mdfyTitle(T* object, const char* newName){
    object->name=newName;
    return OK;
}
```

Ahora bien... cuando releo:

> Nota: se debe realizar una gestión correcta de la memoria.

Creo que algo no estoy haciendo bien. ¿Gestiona mi código correctamente la memoria?
Y yendo más allá, ¿cuando sé que tengo que gestionar la memoria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Cuándo sé que tengo que gestionar la memoria?

Como respuesta amplia a esa amplia pregunta, si tu código usa punteros es posible que tengas que gestionar memoria.

Viniendo de [java](/questions/tagged/java) y [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) estarás familiarizado con que las clases que manejan cadenas de caracteres son invariantes en esos lenguajes. Es decir, que cuando en esos lenguajes concatenas dos cadenas no modificas una de las cadenas si no que se genera una nueva:

```
String hola = "Hola".
String mensaje = hola.Append(" mundo!");
```

El lenguaje [c](/questions/tagged/c) no dispone de esos mecanismos: maneja la memoria en crudo. Para almacenar una cadena de caracteres debes solicitar memoria para alojar todos los caracteres de dicha cadena más uno adicional (para marcar el final de cadena con el carácter nulo `'\0'`), así que siguiendo el ejemplo anterior:

```
        char *hola = "Hola";
/* 1 */ char *mensaje = malloc(12); // 'Hola' (4) + ' mundo!' (7) + '\0' (1)
/* 2 */ strcpy(mensaje, hola);      // Copiar 'Hola'
/* 3 */ strcat(mensaje, " mundo!"); // Concatenar ' mundo!'

// … usar cadena

/* 4 */ free(mensaje); // Liberar memoria
```

La variable de destino de la concatenación no tiene memoria asignada

1. Hay que asignarle memoria ([`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc)).
2. Una vez tiene memoria no tiene contenido así que hay que darle contenido ([`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy)).
3. Una vez tiene contenido aún no hemos concatenado nada así que concatenamos ([`strcat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat)).
4. Una vez hemos usado la memoria pedida con `malloc` debemos liberarla con [`free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free).

Como ves, cada cadena de caracteres vive en un espacio de memoria apuntado por un puntero, así que en tu implementación:

```
tError T_mdfyTitle(T* object, const char* newName){
    object->name=newName;
    return OK;
}
```

Estás copiando el puntero (no el contenido apuntado). Esto a priori no es un error si es tu intención, pero si la cadena original (la apuntada por el argumento `newName`) desaparece, el `object->name` quedará apuntando a memoria no válida. La *gestión correcta de memoria* sería:

1. Consultar la longitud de la cadena apuntada por `newName` con [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen).
2. Reservar la memoria necesaria (contando el `'\0'`) sobre  `object->name` con `malloc`.
3. Copiar el contenido apuntado por `newName` en la memoria apuntada por `object->name` con `strcpy` o [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy).
4. Cuando vaya a liberarse una instancia de `T`, debe hacerse `free` sobre su puntero `name`.